# Array for Word bookmarks and sheet names

Tags: arrays, excel, ms-word, bookmarks, vba

I've been doing some VBA stuff lately but i don't know what directions to take.
Someone here helped me with the copy to Word, i've lost the topic but thanks a lot!
Is there a better way to read in the BookMarks and how can i get them to link the right sheet in this line;

```
MyArray(i) 
'needs to go in to;
wb.worksheet(Myarray(i)).range("A1:BA3000")
```

I've been spending way to many hours on the array part.

```
Private Sub ranges()

Dim NamedRange As name
    Dim nm As name
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim Lr As Long
    Dim Lc As Long
    Dim Rng As range
    Dim Bm As name
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Fill As range
    Dim wd As Word.Application
Set wd = New Word.Application
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'Workbooks("C:\Excel")
    Set aWs = ActiveSheet
'array with names of the word bookmarks
        Dim myArray(38)

myArray(0) = ("Tappunten")
myArray(1) = ("test1")
myArray(2) = ("Groslijst")
myArray(3) = ("J01_2")
myArray(4) = ("D01")
myArray(5) = ("D03")
myArray(6) = ("W01")
myArray(7) = ("W02")
myArray(8) = ("W03")
myArray(9) = ("W04")
myArray(10) = ("M01")
myArray(11) = ("M03")
myArray(12) = ("M04")
myArray(13) = ("M05")
myArray(14) = ("HJ01")
myArray(15) = ("J01")
myArray(16) = ("M02")
myArray(17) = ("J03")
myArray(18) = ("J04")
myArray(19) = ("J05")
myArray(20) = ("J06")
myArray(21) = ("J07")
myArray(22) = ("J08")
myArray(23) = ("J09")
myArray(24) = ("J10")
myArray(25) = ("J11")
myArray(26) = ("J12")
myArray(27) = ("J13")
myArray(28) = ("J14")
myArray(29) = ("J15")
myArray(30) = ("OT03")
myArray(31) = ("OT06")
myArray(32) = ("OT07")
myArray(33) = ("Checklist")
myArray(34) = ("ObjectGegevens")
myArray(35) = ("Grondstof")
myArray(36) = ("Drinkwaterinstallatie")
myArray(37) = ("WTB")
myArray(38) = ("Warmwaterleidingnet")

    'array for the worksheets on the excel sheets
        Dim myArray2(38)

myArray2(0) = Worksheets(1).name
myArray2(1) = Worksheets(1).name
myArray2(2) = Worksheets(42).name
myArray2(3) = Worksheets(17).name
myArray2(4) = Worksheets(2).name
myArray2(5) = Worksheets(15).name
myArray2(6) = Worksheets(22).name
myArray2(7) = Worksheets(3).name
myArray2(8) = Worksheets(28).name
myArray2(9) = Worksheets(29).name
myArray2(10) = Worksheets(4).name
myArray2(11) = Worksheets(6).name
myArray2(12) = Worksheets(29).name
myArray2(13) = Worksheets(46).name
myArray2(14) = Worksheets(7).name
myArray2(15) = Worksheets(16).name
myArray2(16) = Worksheets(5).name
myArray2(17) = Worksheets(13).name
myArray2(18) = Worksheets(12).name
myArray2(19) = Worksheets(47).name
myArray2(20) = Worksheets(9).name
myArray2(21) = Worksheets(13).name
myArray2(22) = Worksheets(14).name
myArray2(23) = Worksheets(14).name
myArray2(24) = Worksheets(32).name
myArray2(25) = Worksheets(1).name
myArray2(26) = Worksheets(1).name
myArray2(27) = Worksheets(1).name
myArray2(28) = Worksheets(1).name
myArray2(29) = Worksheets(8).name
myArray2(30) = Worksheets(19).name
myArray2(31) = Worksheets(33).name
myArray2(32) = Worksheets(18).name
myArray2(33) = Worksheets(27).name
myArray2(34) = Worksheets(25).name
myArray2(35) = Worksheets(36).name
myArray2(36) = Worksheets(26).name
myArray2(37) = Worksheets(20).name
myArray2(38) = Worksheets(38).name


i = 1

For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If nm.Visible Then
        Set NamedRange = wb.Names.Item(i)
        Set ws = NamedRange.RefersToRange.Parent
    End If

        Lr = wb.worksheet(Myarray(i)).range("A1:BA3000").Find(What:="*", _ LookIn:=xlValues, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _ SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, 
            SearchFormat:=False).Row
        Lc = wb.worksheet(Myarray(i)).range("A1:BA3000").Find(What:="*", _ LookIn:=xlValues, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _ SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            SearchFormat:=False).Column

    Set Rng = ws.range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(Lr, Lc))

With wd
        .Visible = True
        .WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
    With .Documents.Add(Template:="C:\RABP sjabloon clean.dotx")
        With .Bookmarks
            myArray(i).range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, _
                WordFormatting:=True, RTF:=False
            Rng.Copy ws.range(i)
        End With
    End With
End With
        i = i + 1
    Next nm
End Sub
```

Comment: `wb.ws.` should just be `ws.`.  `ws` is an object - it is not a method or property of the `wb` object.

Comment: I only read that now! So that's why i had those weird errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways that you could populate your array:

Method 1:

`myArray = Split("Tappunten test1 Groslijst ...", " ")`

Method 2:

```
Sub LoopThroughBookmarks()
    Dim oBookmark As Bookmark
    Dim myArray() As String
    ReDim Preserve myArray(0)
    For Each oBookmark In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        ReDim Preserve myArray(UBound(myArray) + 1)
        myArray(UBound(myArray) - 1) = oBookmark.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

---

The bookmarks will be entered in the order in which they occur in the document, you may want to add some validation for the bookmarks so that you don't add some by mistake.

I've no idea how to match the bookmarks to the 2nd array :-/

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. I think i misunderstood how i could use the array for my goals. I have many different named ranges and some need to go to a BookMark in word. I thought loading the named ranges and bookmarks onto an array would be a good way to cycle through each one. Instead i should have gone and "Dim" the needed ranges and load and then load the ranges into the word doc. "for worksheet(1, 3, 11, 42...) find last row and column. Set  rng1, 2, 3, 4...= range(A1, cells(lastCol, lastRow)). Then ->  rng1.coppy item("bookmark1").range.PasteExcelTable.

Comment: No worries. Yes... I thought the loop example with the bookmarks might help, feel free to mark it as an answer (always good to close out questions) or if you need more just ask. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using these 2 pieces of code;

```
   Sub Copy_to_word()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim i As Long
Dim names As Range

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

    'location of the word template
Const StrDocNm As String = "C:\Word template V2.0.dotx"
If Dir(StrDocNm) = "" Then Debug.Print "file missing"
If Dir(StrDocNm) = MsgBox "Template not found"
If Dir(StrDocNm) = "" Then Exit Sub
   'Could probebly make it a bit neather
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(Template:=StrDocNm)
wdApp.Visible = True
   'All the named ranges have the same name as the bookmark
With ThisWorkbook
  For i = 1 To .names.Count

On Error GoTo LosseCell:
    .names(i).RefersToRange.Copy
    Debug.Print .names(i).Name
        'When the range is copied it starts the next macro.
        'if there's an error it goes tot the next name range 
    Call PasteBookmark(wdDoc, .names(i).Name)
LosseCell:

  Next
End With


Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
   'because it takes some time it had the events and screenupdating turned off
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

The second marcro is the part that pastes the range in to word;

```
Sub PasteBookmark(wdDoc As Word.Document, strBkMk As String)
Dim wdRng As Word.Range

With wdDoc
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'not sure if this helps to be honest
  Application.EnableEvents = True   'not sure if this helps to be honest

  If .Bookmarks.Exists(strBkMk) Then

    Set wdRng = .Bookmarks(strBkMk).Range
 wdRng.Paste
    .Bookmarks.Add strBkMk, wdRng

  End If
End With
Set wdRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Because the ranges vary in size i also have a macro that resizes the named ranges that can vary in row count;

```
Sub RangesAanpassen()

  Dim NmdRngNames As Variant
  Dim myLastRow As Long
  Dim StrWsNaam As String
  Dim strRangeNaam As String
  Dim namRange As Name
  Dim wsRange As Worksheet
  Dim n As Variant

  'the ranges that need to be resized are named the same as the sheets there
  'on. It gave a lot of troubles because the sheets had names like "D01". 
  'Had to change all of them to a name that didn't look like a cell.

  NmdRngNames = Array("D_03", "D_01", "J_01", "_6.4.3_Temperatuurmetingen", 
  "WTB", "Tappunten", "_6.4.2_Tappunten_inv", "Voorblad")

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False


For Each n In NmdRngNames

strRangeNaam = n
On Error GoTo NextN: when the range is empty a "no object" error shows.
Set namRange = ActiveWorkbook.names.Item(strRangeNaam)
Set wsRange = Range(strRangeNaam).Worksheet

  With wsRange
      'the last cell can be anywhere in columns A to Z. 
    myLastRow = .Columns("A:Z").Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, _ 
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
  End With
  With namRange
    .RefersTo = wsRange.Range(wsRange.Cells(1, 1), _
                wsRange.Cells(myLastRow, 1))
  End With
NextN:

Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

Thanks for the great forum!